# .net core 2.0 global filter for IsDeleted column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, global-filter

I want to add global filter for deleted row by entity framework. And i achieve this by this code in DbContext class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But for every table, i am adding new row to OnModelCreating method. How can i do this with one row for every table like this?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it can solve this issue. But in this solution, we must implement interface for every class. I want more generic solution. Is there another way? @KirylKhadanovich

Comment: Take the code from the first linked duplicate, replace `IsActive` with `IsDeleted` and wrap the `Expression.Property(…)` with `Expression.Not(…)`

Comment: Thanks. It worked.